# cloud robotics engine for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

May I know if there exist a cloud platform for ROS computations. I know one 'Rapyuta' which was pretty much active 2 years ago. Now they have neither support for 14.04 nor for Indigo.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213227/cloud-robotics-engine-for-ros/) by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rapyuta is currently going through a major revision and it is planned to be release in early 2016, http://rapyuta.org.

Other works from the top my head:

1. https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.ArchitectureDescription.I2ND.Robotics
2. http://www.robotconcert.org/index.php/Main_Page

---

Originally posted by [gajamohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23176/gajamohan/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1